# How to suspend /kill third party scripts in a site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, database

In my page, I have third party scripts running, named fls.doubleclick. It was affecting the page performance since the request were sent to the servers and it had a poor response time.

I tried implementing this code to postpone the script request after 5 seconds on page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fltFunction()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        //my third party script goes here
    },5000); 
}       
fltFunction();
</script>
```

Is there a way that I could suspend or kill the request that is going to the server after a certain time say after 10 seconds?

Comment: Short answer: no. But thanks for warning us so we don't go to your site...

Comment: I'm confused on what you mean by "my third party script". What exactly does your third party script do? And what kind of request is being sent to the server that you want to kill after 10 seconds?

Comment: You could try to remove that script element. But I've never tried something like this before, so no guarantees :D

Comment: @lan, the third party script in my site does the download tracking. For example tracking download of a pdf or some file. I want to kill that request after timeout so as to improve my page performance.